# How to use CASE after arithmetic in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering how I would use CASE after calculating. Basically I want to calculate a value and if that value returns larger than 1 I want to set it to 1.

Heres what I got so far:

`SELECT (HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) / (SELECT AVG(HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) FROM EDUCATIONPROFILE) as res, case when res > 1 then 1 else res END AS result FROM EDUCATIONPROFILE ORDER BY cid ASC`

However, I get an invalid identifer error "RES": invalid identifier. Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT LEAST( (HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) / AVG(HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) OVER (),
              1
            ) as res
FROM EDUCATIONPROFILE
ORDER BY cid ASC
```